# Navigate with BottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native, maybe it's a weird question,
I have a simple app with a BottomTabNavigator with 4 tabs in it: A, B, C, D.

on screen "A" I have a button that when you click on you will go to screen "E" that is not suppose to be visible on the bottom tabs.

I tried to add that navigation.navigate("E") but it seems to work only when I actually add that E to the bottomTabs. But I don't need that E screen visible on the bottom tabs, and E should be found only by going to A and pressing on that button.

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Hello I kind off got confused with your question. But If you want to have 4 tabs and another screen (which is not in tab screen) you can use stack navigator. Call screen E in stack Navigator and others in TabNavigator

Comment: @learner I'm sorry if my question is confusing, I tried to ask it as simple as I can... Well I tried stack navigator but where do I implement that stack? If I'll implement it in App.js it will show the stack instead of the actual bottomTabs.

Comment: Can you share with us your navigation file or stack ? and also which version of React navigation used
Normally you have to include BottomTabNavigator into your main Stack

Comment: Na that's alright dw. So this is how you do it. Hold up check my answer in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**STACK**
(App.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

const Stack = createStackNavigator()
export default class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
       <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={"Main"}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen} style={{
           headerShown: false}} />
          <Stack.Screen name="screenE" component={screenE} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
       <NavigationContainer/>
    )
}}
```

**TAB**
(Main Screen)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

export default class Main extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="screenA">
      <Tab.Screen name="screenA" component={screenA} />
      <Tab.Screen name="screenB" component={screenB}  />
      <Tab.Screen name="screenC" component={screenC}  />
      <Tab.Screen name="screenD" component={screenD}  />
    </Tab.Navigator>
)}}
```

If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask. If there is anything wrong it please feel free to comment.

Comment: I edited my answer. It shows how to remove header as well.